# On XP many application won't start, get fixed after scandisk, but the the same again after reboot

Tags: windows-xp, boot, scan-disk

So I've got Win XP, after startup I'm unable to run many applications (like Google Chrome, Opera, Lightroom) while some (Word for example) are running OK. If I make a scandisk (during bootup) the things get fixed, but only till the next reboot, when everithing's the same again.
Any idea? How can I diagnose the problem?

Comment: I've seen that the applications start also in safemode and in Event Viewer I've seen that Windows is having trouble loading NetBIOS, IPSec and a couple of other drivers. Could it be a hard drive issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a precaution, Back up your data and prepare to have hard d rive failure. [Install Speedfan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) and see if there are any SMART errors.

You can also download and run your hard drive manufacturers diagnostic tool to test the hard drive, back up your data before doing anything else.

If the hard drive checks out OK, I suspect Malware, [see my post here](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware/157533#157533)

Comment: MBAM solved the issue.